# Rendering collection view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I am having problems understanding how to render a collection in a view using a template.  Here is my code:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="details">
<ul>
<% _.each(?, function(person)  { %>
<li><%= person.name %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
</script>

<script>
var m = Backbone.Model.extend();

var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'retrieve.php',
        model: m
 });

var v = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#mydiv'),
        template : _.template($("#details").html()),
        initialize : function() {
        var coll = new c(); 
        coll.fetch({success: function(){alert(JSON.stringify(coll));} });              
        this.render();
        },
        render : function() {
        //what do I put here?
        return this;
       }
});

var view = new v();
```

I am confused about how to get the data returned from my php file into the template.  What code do I need in the view and ._each?   My php code is returning:

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"John","age":"5"},{"id":"2","name":"Jane","age":"2"}]
```

and I see this in the alert().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call your `render` function from the `success` handler as a `collection.fetch` returns result asynchronously (you can also [bind](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) `render` function to a collection `reset` event).

```
var v = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#mydiv',
    template : _.template($("#details").html()),
    initialize : function() {
      var self = this, 
          coll = new c(); 
      coll.fetch({ success: function(){ self.render() ; } });              
    },
    render : function() {
      // the persons will be "visible" in your template
      this.$el.html(this.template({ persons: this.coll.toJSON() }));
      return this;
    }
});
```

And in the template refer to the same `persons` object

```
<script type="text/template" id="details">
  <ul> 
    <% _.each(persons, function(person)  { %>
      <li><%= person.name %></li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
</script>
```

**Update:**

I've created the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superhacker/P2JR8/3/), but I had to modify the original source code as I can't use your `retrieve.php` endpoint

Comment: Hmm!  I follow the logic but for some reason I can't get it to work. I don't see anything when I run the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bad approach because if any of your models change, you need to re render your whole collection to reflect that change in the view.

Comment: @Jaseem Hi. if you think that this is a bad approach, then can you please share something which you consider as a better approach? P.S. I am still new to backbone.js

Answer (score 1):

What you have asked is a generic question of how to use a collection to generate a view. Most of them are comfortable with generating a view with a model, but not with a collection. I followed the following tutorial [Binding a collection to a view](http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/). Might be helpful for you also.